# Scrollable Text On Object

Tags: mesh, text, objects

I want to put Scrollable Text On Object / Mesh.
I looked after it on YT but I did not find anything useful.
How could I do this?

Comment: Don't forget to tell us what engine or tech stack you're using! When you say "scrollable text", do you mean text that moves like the old Marquee HTML element? Or do you mean text that the player can navigate with some kind of control input? Can you tell us anything about the shape/topology of the meshes you're working with, or show us a mock-up of the effect you want?

Comment: I am sorry, Is it possible to delete this post, because I want to make a new one where I will be more specific?

Comment: You can do even better: use the "edit" link at the bottom of your question to update it to look just the way you want.